# What are these brown ladybug-like bugs with yellow and white spots on the back side?

Tags: identification, pest-control, pests, bugs, runner-beans

They are about half the size of a ladybug, I found them on my runner beans.

[image: Bugs on leaf]
[image: Bugs on stem]

Location: London, England, UK

Comment: Do you have a worry about these beetles?  They all are predators, not plant eaters.  These beetles do what lady bugs do and that is work as a predator eating harmful insects...only some, I guess, bite.  I've felt this.  Ouch.  I thought all Lady bugs bit.  They will not hurt your plants whatsoever.  They are a major benefit and are only temporarily visiting your property.  They might overwinter in your attic (how smart is that)?  This beetle looks like some 4 spotted species, not 2 nor 14.  That is how far ranging this insect has become.  Still a good guy.

Comment: Are the leaves being eaten, and are there any eggs on the undersides of the leaves?

Comment: I don't think so. I haven't killed them or anything, I assumed they've been eating the aphids that usually appear on the runner beans

Comment: If there are no aphids, then I would worry it's some type of bean beetle which shred the leaves and eat the bean seeds

Comment: @GrahamChiu - interesting find. Do you have any idea how to check if it might be a bean beetle short of waiting and seeing if it is shredding anything? FYI, we HAVE had almost no bean crop thus far (expected months ago), but we've only spotted these beetles for the first time yesterday...

Comment: I think observation is required to see what they're eating. If you see them eating aphids then fine. But they are eating something.

Comment: Could you write up your comment as an answer? then I can mark it as accepted if you turn out to be right

Comment: I found this chap and some relatives on my French beans today![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeCIk.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr6LH.jpg)

Comment: Hi Martin, no worry, this is not a bad insect. An answer is not the way to communicate "I have the same bug here". The idea is to answer the question, and if you have another question, use the appropriate button. e.g. you may ask "is it a related bug as the one in this question?"... See also [ask]

Comment: @J.Chomel - this IS a bad insect as proved by Graham Chiu's comment on the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nymph (pre-adult stage) of either a stink/shield bug or a soldier bug. Most likely on bean it is a stink bug, green stink bug (Nezara viridula). The difference for a gardener is important, stink bugs tend to be harmful, attacking the beans but soldier bugs are a beneficial insect, attacking other insects. Keep looking for adults, then you can identify the correct type of bug more easily.

Comment: Now that this has been posted, I HAVE found the most similar picture yet: https://ipmguidelinesforgrains.com.au/pests/pod-sucking-bugs-in-summer-pulses/   I think you've got it.

Comment: https://www.britishbugs.org.uk/heteroptera/idcards/life_stages.html 3rd instar of Nezara viridula.

Answer (score 1):

This beetle is the closest I could get for now.  The dang name gave me a migraine!  Propytea quatuordecimpunctator; the 14 spot Asian Lady Beetle.

https://www.jungledragon.com/image/4616/14-spot_ladybirds_mating.html

Here is one for a 2 spot ladybird...not bug, bird! Adalia bipunctata
[2-spot lady bird](http://stippen.nl/fotos1/aADABIP9.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is the pre adult stage of the brown marmorated stink bug
I have them on my runner beans in Vancouver BC
There is currently no control methods
I squish them when I can